# Correct place to set my php error handler in Laravel 5

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I want to follow this patterns described here http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch08_17.htm which convers PHP Errors or Warnings into exemptions.

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_error_handler('pc_error_handler');

```
function pc_error_handler($errno, $error, $file, $line, $context) {
    $message = "[ERROR][$errno][$error][$file:$line]";
    print "$message";
    print_r($context);
}
```

Where exactly should I put this code in the Laravel 5 Framework? Where would it make sense and work correctly?

Comment: In a config file or bootstrap file

Comment: I thought PHP errors where automatically converted to exception in laravel without having to modify anything (in `homestead` it's ok)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel already treats all PHP errors/warnings as exceptions.

See http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/errors#handling-errors for details.